# Fastest random selection WHERE column X is Y (NULL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I am using:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
  table AS t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table where column_x is null)) AS id
  ) AS t2 
WHERE 
  t1.id >= t2.id
  and column_x is null
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This is normally extremely fast however when I include the highlighted column_x being Y (null) condition, it gets slow.

What would be the fastest random querying solution where the records' column X is null?

ID is PK, column X is int(4). Table contains about a million records and over 1 GB in total size doubling itself every 24 hours currently.

column_x is indexed.

Column ID may not be consecutive.

The DB engine used in this case is InnoDB.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, it is indexed and yet the query starts to take too long as the DB grows AND a lot of column_x becomes NOT NULL.

Comment: Is the table using MyISAM or InnoDB engine? Can you try adding a compound index on `(column_x, id)`?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the `EXPLAIN` plan?

Comment: The line with the Order By has a typo, right? It should be: `ORDER BY t1.id ASC`

Comment: Hello, it is a typo. Fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Getting a genuinely random record can be slow. There's not really much getting around this fact; if you want it to be truly random, then the query has to load all the relevant data in order to know which records it has to choose from.

Fortunately however, there are quicker ways of doing it. They're not properly random, but if you're happy to trade a bit of pure randomness for speed, then they should be good enough for most purposes.

With that in mind, the fastest way to get a "random" record is to add an extra column to your DB, which is populated with a random value. Perhaps a salted MD5 hash of the primary key? Whatever. Add appropriate indexes on this column, and then simply add the column to your `ORDER BY` clause in the query, and you'll get your records back in a random order.

To get a single random record, simply specify `LIMIT 1` and add a `WHERE random_field > $random_value` where random value would be a value in the range of your new field (say an MD5 hash of a random number, for example).

Of course the down side here is that although your records will be in a random order, they'll be stuck in the same random order. I did say it was trading perfection for query speed. You can get around this by updating them periodically with fresh values, but I guess that could be a problem for you if you need to keep it fresh.

The other down-side is that adding an extra column might be too much to ask if you have storage constraints and your DB is already massive in size, or if you have a strict DBA to get past before you can add columns. But again, you have to trade off something; if you want the query speed, you need this extra column.

Anyway, I hope that helped.

Comment: This is the only method proposed so far which provides truly uniform probabilities. Gaps in the IDs don't matter. Easy to implement and to index. +1

Answer (score 1):

Have you ran `explain` on the query? What was the output?

Why not store or cache the value of : `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table where column_x is null` and use that as a variable. your query would then become:

```
$rand = rand(0, $storedOrCachedMaxId);

SELECT * 
FROM 
  table AS t1
WHERE 
  t1.id >= $rand
  and column_x is null
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

A simpler query will likely be easier on the db.

Know that if your data contains sizable holes - you *aren't* going to get consistently random results with these kind of queries.

Comment: Value of column X changes constantly. With each query, all the column_x's must be checked to find out which ones are still NULL.

Comment: That sounds a bit odd, but doesn't change my answer - you don't really need to put `column_x is null` in your `MAX(id)` query. In the rare-ish cicumstance you get no result, you could just query again inverting the logic test `t1.id < $rand`. You still need to add the `explain` result to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a join, nor an order by, nor a limit 1 (providing the ids are unique).

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  column_x IS NULL
   AND id = ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM myTable), 0)
```

Comment: except ids aren't sequencial so that'll return 1 **or 0** rows.

Comment: The ids don't need to be sequential - but looking again - if the id of the row has a column_x value then nothing would be returned - so I'll have another look.

Comment: Hello, this query unfortunately won't work when a column is involved. It will return empty since a random ID between 0 and the maximum id of a record where column X is NULL might belong to a column where column X is not NULL.

Comment: you could however use `AND id >= ... LIMIT 1`. The join in the query in the question is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to MySQL syntax, but digging a little further I think a dynamic query might work. We select the Nth row, where the Nth is random:

```
SELECT @r := CAST(COUNT(1)*RAND() AS UNSIGNED) FROM table WHERE column_x is null;

PREPARE stmt FROM
'SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column_x is null
LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?';

EXECUTE stmt USING @r;
```

Comment: A query with a huge offset is very inefficient