# How would I select the 1st, 12th, 68th or even 651st record with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine I have a MySQL database table with 1,000 records in it and I wanted to select 1 record at random.

The records do not have an ID column where the numbers go up +1 each time. The ID numbers are randomly generated so the first records ID could be '932151540' and the second records ID could be '541577961'.

The only way I can think of selecting 1 record at random is by finding out how many records there are in total. Pick a random number between 1 and however many there are (say the random number was 467). Then getting the 467th record.

How would I do this using PHP?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why use a random number instead of an incrementing ID?

Comment: Sometimes the structure of a database schema is out of the control of the developer. For example if you are doing contract work for a 3rd party company with their existing database. You have no control. You simply have to find the proper solution even if what you have to work with was not implemented properly to begin with.

Comment: Because... The ID's will be used in the URL to pick out information from a record. I don't want people to be able to just +1 to the URL to see the next records information.

Comment: have 2 ids, one for the public and one for internal use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Possibly of no consequence but `ORDER BY RAND` is not appropriate for a large table. There are [a number of other techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677767/fastest-random-selection-where-column-x-is-y-null) which can be used

Comment: You are correct, due to how the table is indexed. Based off of the question, I'm assuming the table is not gigantic.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative query you could use is

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((1/COUNT(*))*10) FROM myTable) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;` Which will yield much better performance as the size of your table increases.

To quote the author:

> This method uses ORDER BY RAND(), but only on a small percentage of
>   the table rows; this percentage is based upon how many rows you want,
>   LIMIT 1, divided by how many rows the table has, COUNT(*), and then
>   multiply that figure by 10 to avoid returning less rows than you
>   request. I developed this method after reading [How to select random
>   rows in MySQL @ rndblog.com](http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-select-random-rows-in-mysql/).

Read the full post [here](http://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/) for a detailed explanation and performance analysis, along with other alternatives which are possibly not applicable in your case..

Answer (score 0):

im using this instead of slow **ORDER BY rand()**, quite faster.

```
$table = "mytable";
$offset_result = mysql_query("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM ".$table.";");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object($offset_result);
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." LIMIT ".$offset.", 1;"); 
$result_row = mysql_fetch_row($result);  // point to record
$row = $result_row[0];
```