# Select random row that exists in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Currently Using:

```
$randomQuery = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` >= RAND() * (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table`) LIMIT 1"));
```

Table Structure:

```
id:
 2 
 4
 5
```

I want to make sure it's selecting an existing row. For example, it shouldn't be able to use 1 or 3 in its randomizing function. Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: This is biased depending of the holes but I don't see how this could select a non existing row.

Comment: Any solution using `RAND()` will be slow because it can't do an index. For faster, properly indexed solution, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677767/fastest-random-selection-where-column-x-is-y-null/10677869#10677869

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

would do the trick.

See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: Does this take into account deleted rows?

Comment: deleted rows - i think - are removed from the storage engine, so they will not be included in the result. If you only have a deleted flag in the row instead of `DELETE`ing the row completely you need to add a `WHERE deleted=0` to your statement

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this will work, but will be slow because it won't use an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query **does** take care of the holes as it simply compares the id of a row to the random value you compute and doesn't try to fetch a row having a random id.

Its problem is that it gives you a non uniform probability : Any row following a big hole has a bigger probability of being selected.

That's the reason why it's suggested to use the mysql trick `ORDER BY RAND()` (see other answers) as the randomization will be quasi uniform.