# Show limited random rows through SQL

Tags: mysql

I am selecting values from sql table using select command. It returns 10 values from table. But i want to show 3 values *randomly*.

Comment: Everyone is suggesting `order by rand()`. This is fine if you have a small table, but will be very slow if you've got a lot of data. If it is too slow for you, see my answer here for alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677767/fastest-random-selection-where-column-x-is-y-null/10677869#10677869

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
order by rand()
limit 3
```

Comment: `order by rand()` will be very slow if you have a large table.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea on big tables:

```
select * from mytable order by rand() limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can do like this for small table:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3;
```

But if you have big table, then you can select using `fragmentation` of resultset....SUppose, your table contains 200K of rows and you only need to select 100 rows randomly,then you can calculate fragment of resultset.....The fragment of resultset of given table will be 0.0005 which later can be used like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE RAND()<=0.0005
```

To get exactly 100 rows ,you can increase the fragment a little bit and can be used like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE RAND()<=0.0006 LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

but be aware that using **ORDER BY RAND()**, **[according to this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)**,  `ORDER BY RAND()` is already behind the optimized query at only 100 rows in the table.

**[This article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)** shows different techniques on generating random records on performance basis.